# Porting from Lua 5.1 to 5.2

Tags: c#, c++, lua, porting, lua-5.2

I'm having some issues porting some older Lua 5.1 code to Lua 5.2.  I would like to be able to use the stock Lua 5.2 dll/lib, so any porting would need to be completed using the existing API for Lua 5.2.  To make it a little more complicated, I'm using `DllImport` to P/Invoke some of the Lua API calls.  This means any of the `#define` shortcuts offered will not work.  For example using `lua_pushglobaltable` wont be possible.  Most of the updates are needed because `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` is not longer accessible.

What I have so far is the following:

---

1a) Replace

```
lua_pushstring(luaState, "tablename");
lua_settable(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // LUA_REGISTRYINDEX no longer accessible
```

1b) With

```
lua_setglobal(luaState, "tablename");
```

---

2a) Replace

```
lua_pushstring(luaState, "tablename");
lua_gettable(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // LUA_REGISTRYINDEX no longer accessible
```

2b) With

```
lua_getglobal(luaState, "tablename");
```

---

3a) Replace

```
lua_pushvalue(luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

3b) With

```
// not sure, something equivalent to lua_pushglobaltable(L)
```

---

4a) Replace

```
lua_replace(luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

4b) With

```
// I dont even have a guess here
```

---

5a) Replace

```
luaL_ref(luaState, (int)LuaIndexes.LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // also luaL_unref
```

5b) With

```
luaL_ref(luaState, <some arbitrary constant>); // this is probably wrong
```

---

6a) Replace

```
lua_rawgeti(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, reference);
```

6b) With

```
lua_rawgeti(luaState, <same arbitrary constant>, reference); // this is probably wrong
```

---

7a) Replace

```
lua_pcall(IntPtr luaState, int nArgs, int nResults, int errfunc);
```

7b) With

```
lua_pcallk(IntPtr luaState, int nArgs, int nResults, int errfunc, int ctx, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]LuaCSFunction function);
lua_pcallk(luaState, nArgs, nResults, errfunc, 0, null);
```

---

8a) Replace

```
lua_getfield(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, meta);
```

8b) With

```
luaL_setmetatable(IntPtr luaState, string meta);
```

---

9a) Replace

```
lua_rawset(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

9b) With

```
lua_settable(luaState, -3);
```

Right now everything compiles, but I get memory access violation exceptions, which means I probably substituted something incorrectly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The registry is not the same as the global table. The global table was `LUA_GLOBALSINDEX` in lua 5.1.

Comment: Have you looked at [Changes in the API](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#8.3)?

Comment: @Etan - I did come across that page, but it doesnt provide a translation, only recommendation to get the global environment from the registry.  I very easily could be confusing the registry and global tables.

Comment: It does explicitly indicate that you get one from the other so, while yes some confusion is possible, it is fairly clear that they aren't the same. Also `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` hasn't gone anywhere so your questions about replacing that with something else are unnecessary.

Comment: Replacing a `get` call with a `set` call isn't exactly a meaningful statement either (item `11`) and `luaL_getmetatable` [still exists in lua 5.2](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_getmetatable).

Comment: Right, `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` was a constant value, so before we could just hardcode it, but that is no longer the case in 5.2.  `luaL_getmetatable` is a #define and not accessible through P/Invoke.  `11)` is actually number `9)` so I've removed it (I had a helper function called the same thing that pointed to `lua_getfield...`

Comment: `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` is still a define in 5.2 from what I can see.

Comment: Yes, `luaL_getmetatable` is a define. So you can't use that but you can use what it is a define for, no? Which is [`(lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, (n)))`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lauxlib.h.html#luaL_getmetatable).

Comment: But again, I dont know what `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` is.  Its no longer `-10000`.  So before I could do `lua_getfield(L, -10000, n)`, but now I cant.  because its a `pseudo-index`.

Comment: It was **always** a [`pseudo-index`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#3.3). Have you looked at the [5.2 define for it](http://www.lua.org/source/5.2/lua.h.html#LUA_REGISTRYINDEX)?

Comment: If I hardcode LUA_REGISTRYINDEX to `-1001000`, the first call to `lua_pushvalue(luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);` throws a `AccessViolationException`.  However in 5.1, when the value was `-10000` it worked.

Comment: If I hardocde LUA_REGISTRYINDEX to `-16000`, the first call to `lua_settable(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);` throws a `AccessViolationException`.  This also worked in 5.1.

Comment: 4 and 5 are the same example, is this a copy paste error?

Comment: You need to find out what `LUAI_BITSINT` is set to to find out what the value of `LUAI_MAXSTACK` is before you can find out what `LUA_REGISTRYINDEX` is.

Comment: @greatwolf - Yeah I think I just copied it twice, updated.

Comment: @Etan - The examples in my comments are with both of the possible options.  Hardcoding to either one doesnt seem to work.  Just for completeness, its set to `#define LUAI_BITSINT 32`

Comment: Ah, I missed the difference there. Apologies. Compile a small program against the appropriate header that prints out the value and see what it is?

Comment: Also try preprocessing c source it'll show exactly what those constants are.

Comment: I'm still a little unclear why, you need to hardcode those pseudo-indices since that's kind of fragile. It should be treated as implementation detail.

Comment: @greatwolf - I'm not trying to hardcore them, I'm looking for how to update the code so it no longer uses those values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've managed to upgrade this, so I'll add the details of what I did below and the conversion.  I created a C wrapper into the LUA lower level API to export the functionality I needed:

1a) Replaced

```
lua_settable(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // LUA_REGISTRYINDEX no longer accessible
```

1b) With

```
lua_settablereg(luaState);
```

2a) Replaced

```
lua_gettable(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // LUA_REGISTRYINDEX no longer accessible
```

2b) With

```
lua_gettablereg(luaState);
```

3a) Replaced

```
lua_pushvalue(luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

3b) With

```
lua_pushglobaltablefunction(luaState)
```

4a) Replaced

```
lua_replace(luaState, LUA_GLOBALSINDEX);
```

4b) With

```
lua_popglobaltablefunction(luaState)
```

5a) Replaced

```
luaL_ref(luaState, (int)LuaIndexes.LUA_REGISTRYINDEX); // also luaL_unref
```

5b) With

```
luaL_refreg(luaState); // also luaL_unrefreg
```

6a) Replaced

```
lua_rawgeti(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, reference);
```

6b) With

```
lua_rawgetireg(luaState, reference);
```

7a) Replaced

```
lua_pcall(luaState, nArgs, nResults, errfunc);
```

7b) With

```
lua_pcalla(luaState, nArgs, nResults, errfunc);
```

8a) Replaced

```
lua_getfield(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, meta);
```

8b) With

```
lua_getfieldreg(luaState, string meta);
```

9a) Replaced

```
lua_rawset(luaState, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
```

9b) With

```
lua_rawsetreg(luaState);
```

Definitions look like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void lua_pushglobaltablefunction(lua_State *L) 
{
   lua_pushglobaltable(L);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_popglobaltablefunction(lua_State *L) 
{
   lua_rawseti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS);
}

__declspec(dllexport) int luaL_regref(lua_State *L) 
{
   return luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void luaL_unregref(lua_State *L, int reference)
{
   luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, reference);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_settablereg(lua_State *L)
{
   lua_settable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_gettablereg(lua_State *L)
{
   lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_rawsetreg(lua_State *L)
{
   lua_rawset(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_rawgetreg(lua_State *L)
{
   lua_rawget(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_rawgetireg(lua_State *L, int reference)
{
   lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, reference);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void lua_getfieldreg(lua_State *L,const char *fieldname)
{
   lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, fieldname);
}

__declspec(dllexport) int luaL_loadbuffername(lua_State *L,const char *buff, int size,const char * name)
{
   return luaL_loadbuffer(L,buff,size,name);
}

__declspec(dllexport) double lua_tonum(lua_State *L, int index)
{
   return lua_tonumber(L, index);
}

__declspec(dllexport) int lua_pcalla(lua_State *L,int nArgs,int nResults,int errfunc)
{
   return lua_pcall(L,nArgs,nResults,errfunc);
}
```